# VBA Excel SQL object variable or with block variable not set

Tags: sql, vba

Hi I keep getting an error when trying to upload to sql. The code have been working before, but I can find what I missed when rewriting the code..

it is falling at line:

```
cmd.CommandText = strSQL
```

the code is pretty simple it takes one column in a sheet and then upload or insert it in to an SQL database. please tell me what code I'm missing, or if I declare something wrong here

```
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Set sTroksheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mlist")
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim strConn As String
Dim SQLstr As String
Dim SQLstrl As String
Dim Password As String
Dim Server_Name As String
Dim User_ID As String
Dim Database_Name As String
Dim Port_Name As String
Dim strTable As String
Dim excel_row As Long
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim rst_recordset As ADODB.Recordset

If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tournament Settings").Range("D4") = vbNullString 
Then
MsgBox "Please setup database connection first in (DB Setup) in top menu"
Exit Sub
Else




Server_Name = Sheets("Software_Setup").Range("c3").Value
Database_Name = Sheets("Software_Setup").Range("c4").Value
User_ID = Sheets("Software_Setup").Range("c5").Value 'id user or username
Password = Sheets("Software_Setup").Range("c6").Value 'Password
Port_Name = Sheets("Software_Setup").Range("c7").Value 'Password


strConn = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver};Server=" & _
        Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & _
        ";Uid=" & User_ID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"





cn.Open strConn
LastRow = sTroksheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).row
strTable = Database_Name & ".TLHMember_List"

strSQL = "INSERT INTO " & strTable & _
" (Player) VALUES "
strSQL2 = ""
For excel_row = 1 To LastRow
strSQL2 = strSQL2 & _
"('" & sTroksheet.Cells(excel_row, 1) & "') ,"
            Next excel_row

            strSQL = strSQL & strSQL2
            Mid(strSQL, Len(strSQL), 1) = ";" ' gets rid of the last comma

            cmd.CommandText = strSQL
            cmd.Execute
cn.Close
End If
```

Comment: Please identify at which line the code is failing, and edit this information into your question.

Comment: `cmd.CommandText = strSQL`

Comment: My guess is you haven't initialized the `cmd` variable with anything -- e.g. `Set cmd = ...` -- hence the error, _Object variable ... not set_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either change this line:

```
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
```

to

```
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
```

or just before error line add new line:

```
Set cmd = new ADODB.Command
cmd.CommandText = strSQL
```

Comment: This just give out a new error "the connection cannot be used to perform this operation. it is either closed or invalid in this context.

Comment: @LasseAnker This should actually be a new question, because it is a different error; but you need to associate a connection with the command, and the connection has to be open when you try to execute the command. Also, whenever you ask about en error, you should make it clear at which line the error occurs -- just throwing error messages into the aether is not ver conducive to helping you with your problem.

Comment: I did correct that like you said the first time.

But I already have the connection open

` cn.Open strConn`

Comment: @LasseAnker But then you threw out a different error. _Those who do not study history are doomed to repeat it._ :)

Comment: @LasseAnker The command also has to be associated with the connection: IIRC `cmd.ActiveConnection = cn`.

Comment: ahh okay mate will do

Comment: Thanks Zev but I can see we are over my lvl now, because I have no clue how to set this. but thanks for the help :)