# Updating SQL Server table with data from a table in different database using Excel VBA

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

I am trying to create Excel VBA to update table SQL Server. This allows my users to perform the update themselves. (using VBA for the first time)

I am getting a runtime error when I run the VBA code.

Here is my code:

```vb
Sub DataUpdateSQLServer()


Dim cnLogs As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rsHeaders As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim rsData As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim uSQL As String


strConn = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;"
strConn = strConn & "DATA SOURCE=abc-dwh ;INITIAL CATALOG=DWH_DEV;"
strConn = strConn & " INTEGRATED SECURITY=sspi;"
strConn = strConn & "User ID= ARGUSGROUP\user;"
strConn = strConn & "Password = Password;"
strConn = strConn & "Trusted_Connection=No"

cnLogs.Open strConn


uSQL = "INSERT INTO DWH_DEV.DBO.GI_PRODUCTION_REPORT_CATALOG (Name, Path, CreationDate) " _
        & "select C1.Name, C1.Path, C1.CreationDate " _
        & "from ReportServer.dbo.Catalog C1 " _
        & "LEFT JOIN DWH_DEV.DBO.GI_PRODUCTION_REPORT_CATALOG C2 " _
        & "ON C1.PATH = C2.Path COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS " _
        & "WHERE (C1.Path LIKE '/Reports/Production/Customer Service%' " _
        & "OR C1.Path LIKE '/Reports/Production/Client Solutions%' " _
        & "OR C1.Path LIKE '/Reports/Production/Finance/Group Insurance%' " _
        & "OR C1.Path LIKE '/Reports/Production/Group Insurance%' " _
        & "OR C1.Path LIKE '/Reports/Production/OTH%') AND C2.PATH IS NULL "

cnLogs.Execute uSQL

End Sub
```

Please help me. TIA.

Comment: You have no spacing in your statement. Put a space after and before the double quotes inside the statement and try that.

Comment: You are getting a runtime error? Can you share the error so others might have a chance? My guess is that you need to add some spaces at the end of each line.

Comment: @WEI_DBA I added the spaces to the code and tried again. Now getting the following error "Command Text was not set for the command object"

Comment: See here for possible answer... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50285285/vba-excel-sql-object-variable-or-with-block-variable-not-set

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get what I need from this link here:
http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?552665-Database-How-do-I-use-an-ADO-Command-object

The changes I made:
1.Added spaces to end of each line of SQL code.
2.Used ADO Command Object as discussed in the link above.

Here is my final code:

```vb
Sub DatafromSQLServer()

Dim cnLogs As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rsHeaders As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim rsData As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim uSQL As String

Dim l_counter As Long: l_counter = 0
Dim strConn As String


Sheets(1).UsedRange.Clear
strConn = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;"
strConn = strConn & "DATA SOURCE=abc-dwh ;INITIAL CATALOG=DWH_DEV;"
strConn = strConn & " INTEGRATED SECURITY=sspi;"
strConn = strConn & "User ID= ARGUSGROUP\user;"
strConn = strConn & "Password = Password"
strConn = strConn & "Trusted_Connection=No"

cnLogs.Open strConn



CSQL = "INSERT INTO DWH_DEV.DBO.GI_PRODUCTION_REPORT_CATALOG (Name, Path, CreationDate)  " _
        & "select C1.Name, C1.Path, C1.CreationDate  " _
        & "from ReportServer.dbo.Catalog C1  " _
        & "LEFT JOIN DWH_DEV.DBO.GI_PRODUCTION_REPORT_CATALOG C2  " _
        & "ON C1.PATH = C2.Path COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS " _
        & "WHERE (C1.Path LIKE '/Reports/Production/Customer Service%'  " _
        & "OR C1.Path LIKE '/Reports/Production/Solutions%'  " _
        & "OR C1.Path LIKE '/Reports/Production/Finance/Insurance%'  " _
        & "OR C1.Path LIKE '/Reports/Production/Insurance%'  " _
        & "OR C1.Path LIKE '/Reports/Production/OTH%') AND C2.PATH IS NULL "



Dim objCommand As ADODB.Command
  Set objCommand = New ADODB.Command
  With objCommand
    .ActiveConnection = cnLogs  'replace this with your Connection object
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .CommandText = CSQL         'replace this with your SQL statement
    .Prepared = True

objCommand.Execute , , adExecuteNoRecords
End With

Set objCommand = Nothing

End Sub
```